# Definition of an automorphism of von Neumann algebra acting on faithful normal state

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$[image]

In Theorem B, the authors define the $\Aut_{\varphi}$. I feel very confused about this definition. If $\alpha\in \Aut(M)$, when $x\in M$, it is sensible to define $\alpha(x)$. But $\varphi\in M_{*}$, is it resonalbe to define $\alpha(\varphi)$?

Comment: I think $\alpha(\phi)$ would usually be understood to be $\phi\circ\alpha$ (or maybe $\phi \circ \alpha^{-1}$, I'm not sure what the usual convention is).

Comment: I think it is sensible to interpret it as  $\phi\circ\alpha$. The above Theorem is from the paper"Structure of bicentralizer algebras and inclusions of type III factors". But in that paper, the authors don't give explanation for that notation.